# Proving $core_G(H)$ is non-trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Question: Let $G$ be a group of order $n^2$, and $H$ a subgroup of order $n$. prove that $H$ contains a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$.
Remarks:

> -It's equivalent to prove that $\cap_{x\in G} H^x$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $G$. because the intersection is the maximal normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$.
>   -The intersection of any two conjugates of $H$ is non-trivial. because if for some $x,y\in G$, $H^x\cap H^y=\{e\}$ then
>   $$
> |H^xH^y|=\frac{|H^x||H^y|}{|H^x\cap H^y|}=n^2
> $$
>   hence $G=(H^x)(H^x)^{x^{-1}y}$, which is impossible.

Comment: There are counterexamples of order $36$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Can you give a counter-example?

Comment: $S_3 \times S_3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : What is $H$?

Comment: Take the diagonal $H=\{(\sigma, \sigma) : \sigma \in S_3\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $|H|=n, |G|=n^2$. Then $H$ has $n$ cosets inside $G$ and $G$ acts on these cosets on the left. Thus, we get a map $\rho: G \to S_n$. The kernel of $\rho$ is a normal subgroup, and any element $g \in \mathrm{Ker}(\rho)$ must satisfy $gH=H$. So $\mathrm{Ker}(\rho) \subset H$.

From the above discussion, we see that a negative answer to your question is the same as the above map having trivial kernel. In other words, we can construct a counter-example by finding a transitive subgroup of size $n^2$ in $S_n$. The smallest possible $n$ which could yield a counter-example is $n=6$ and the comments give a counter-example in this case.